# How to change property value with augeas which position changes in XML?

Tags: xml, puppet, augeas

I have the following problem:

my XML (simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <properties>
    <property name="username">USERNAME</property>
    <property name="anything">blabla</property>
  </properties>
</configuration>
```

I need to replace the Username value with augeas.
It works fine with:

```
augtool> set /files/test.xml/configuration/properties/property[1]/#text NEWUSER
```

But the problem is: The username entry is NOT always on position one. Is there a way in augeas to look for the position with "match" or some kind of regex?

```
augtool> match /files/test.xml/configuration/properties/*/#attribute/name  username
```

works fine an results in

```
/files/test.xml/configuration/properties/property[1]/#attribute/name
```

But i don't know how to use this information when setting a value.

Comment: By default augeas can only view files in /etc/ and /boot, did you create a custom lens ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is:

```
set /files/test.xml/configuration/properties/property[#attribute/name='username']/#text NEWUSER
```

This selects the property (`/files/test.xml/configuration/properties/property`) whose `#attribute/name` subnode matches `username`, and sets its `#text` subnode as `NEWUSER`.

Comment: How can I check insert a new XML element with above attribute if it does not exist, and modify the XML element with the above attribute if it does exist?